# What is the purpose of disabled.aspx under sitecore\service\xdb?

Tags: xdb, sitecore-client, sitecore-services-client

What is the purpose of `disabled.aspx` page under `sitecore\service\xdb`?

When I open this page manually, it's displaying below information.

In which case this page will be executed?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be undocumented feature of Xdb.

I couldn't find any reference in the documentation when you should use this page.

Based on what's written in comment in `App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.xDB\Sitecore.Xdb.config` for setting with name `XdbDisabledUrl`, this page should be used when (obviously) Xdb is disabled. All applications that depend on the Xdb must redirect to this page when Xdb is disabled.

I personally don't understand why would you redirect your visitors to this page to inform them that Xdb is disabled.

Could be that the intended use is for content editors to inform them that Xdb is disabled and that's why they cannot see any data in graphs / charts.

This is config entry that I mentioned above:

```
<!--  XDB DISABLED PAGE HANDLER
The URL of the page that is displayed when the Xdb is disabled. 
All applications that depend on the Xdb must redirect to this page when Xdb is disabled.
-->
<setting name="XdbDisabledUrl" value="/sitecore/service/xdb/disabled.aspx" />
```